# Angular google charts color country on click

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, google-maps, charts

I am using the GeoChart of angular-google-charts. This is my code:

```
type="GeoChart";
  columnNames = [
    [{type: 'string', role: 'data'}]
  ]
  data = [
    ['India'],
    ['Australia'],
    ['Germany'],
    ['United States'],
    ['Brazil'],
    ['Canada'],
    ['France'],
    ['Russia']      
  ];
  options = {
    backgroundColor: '#17263c',
    datalessRegionColor: '#242f3e',
    legend: 'none',
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true,
      textStyle: {
        color: 'black'
      }
    },
    colors: ['#46127A', '#1102BB', '#1633C4', '#3185CE']
  };
  dynamicResize = true;
```

```
<google-chart #chart
   [title]="title"
   [type]="type"
   [data]="data"
   [columnNames]="columnNames"
   [options]="options"
   [dynamicResize]="dynamicResize"
   style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</google-chart>
```

As you can see there is the array `data` (which will be saved in a database lateron)
What I now want to do is to change the color of a country on click. There are two things I don't know:

1. How do I know where I click on the map? If I click on Germany for example how does my program know that it should run `pushCountry("Germany")` for example and if I click on France `pushCountry("France")`
2. How do I really push the countrys so that they are displaxed immediately? For testing I created a button calling the function `this.data.push(['Germany'])` and logged the array, Germany was added but the color in my chart did not change.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 1) with google's geo chart, it won't be possible to know which country was clicked, unless the country has data in the data table already. at which point you could use the select event. 2) the chart must be re-drawn, any time the data or options change.

Comment: okay and how would I redraw the chart in the system I use?

Comment: you can listen for the ready event, which passes the chart wrapper as an argument. then you can call the draw method on the wrapper...

Comment: could you give me some code for that? it is the first time I work with these things and I'm kind of lost :/